Perfect cubes with digit-average at least $7.5$
I found so far the following perfect cubes with a digit-average (in base $10$) with at least $7.5$ :
2   8   8     8.0000000000000000000000000000000000000
12599   1999899757799   98/13     7.5384615384615384615384615384615384615
947229   849894379779889989   15/2     7.5000000000000000000000000000000000000
989353   968397868897889977   68/9     7.5555555555555555555555555555555555556
999423   998269998594899967   15/2     7.5000000000000000000000000000000000000
2131842   9688689596689799688   144/19     7.5789473684210526315789473684210526316
4081435   67988999959868987875   77/10     7.7000000000000000000000000000000000000
4412259   85897988298989489979   153/20     7.6500000000000000000000000000000000000
88316866   688859969398989879749896   181/24     7.5416666666666666666666666666666666667
92827483   799888999896694787687587   181/24     7.5416666666666666666666666666666666667
168685829   4799939897829789888977789   188/25     7.5200000000000000000000000000000000000
190349299   6896898669898996696577899   38/5     7.6000000000000000000000000000000000000
199898999   7987885999690868996696999   188/25     7.5200000000000000000000000000000000000
203922299   8479966879999469866896899   188/25     7.5200000000000000000000000000000000000
206161559   8762399887998778877999879   188/25     7.5200000000000000000000000000000000000
215357183   9987989686997888778847487   188/25     7.5200000000000000000000000000000000000


Is this list complete ? In other words , is the last displayed perfect cube in fact the largest with digit-average $7.5$ or more ? Or are there further or even infinite many solutions ?


Amusing question! Any particular reason that the threshold of interest is $7.5$?

The cube of $n := 10^{10^i} - 10^{78\cdot 10^{i-2}} -10^{53 \cdot 10^{i-2}}$ (for integral $i \geq 3$) seems to have digit-average equal to $\frac{11562\cdot 10^{i-3}-1}{15 \cdot 10^{i-1}} > 7.7$. This would imply that there are infinitely many solutions.

A better parameterisation is to take $n:=10^{4k}-10^{3k+1}-10^{2k+1}-1$ for integral $k\geq 3$, the average digit sum will be $8.25-\frac{31}{6k}$ (unproven).

Even better, fix some integer $m>0$, then the cube of $n:=10^{k\cdot 2^m}-1-\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} 10^{k\cdot(2^m-2^i)+1}$ for integral $k \geq 3$ will have average digit sum equal to $9-\frac{3}{2^m}-\frac{2m^3+9m^2+27m+18}{6k\cdot 2^m}$, implying that we can find infinitely many numbers whose cubes are as close to $9$ as we want.

@jorisperrenet This is amazing ! I would have expected some "brickwall".

The answer is: NO, the list is not complete, not even close.
$9.654.499.999^3=899889864798996889278963499999\implies 226/30=7.53$
$14.422.489.115^3=2999995888877979877897997595875\implies 233/31=7.52$
$17.087.193.298^3 = 4988984988499998899898893979592\implies 235/31=7.58$
$17.851.232.683^3=5688589987988995688999787955987\implies 235/31=7.58$
$18.751.984.083^3=6593889683979798999578997899787\implies 234/31=7.55$
$19.998.639.899^3=7998367989789967795589578889699\implies 233/31=7.52$
$20.405.777.229^3=8496878797688887969682889979989\implies 234/31=7.55$
$21.253.161.559^3=9599986686699689764859698999879\implies 235/31=7.58$
...
I think I will stop here...

Note: The below approximation assumes that the digits are all random. For arbitrary numbers and digits not near the endpoints, this isn’t a bad approximation, but if we’re looking for numbers with special properties (like near 99999…), then there might be many special cases. Peter in a comment pointed out there infinitely many  examples of the form $(10^a-10^b-10^c-1)^3$ with highish average digits which suggests that the below heuristic is not sufficient for showing non-existence.
Note that you’d expect there to be lots of numbers, even past $10^{15}$. If $n$ has $10$ digits, $n^3$ has $45$ digits, and so you’d expat their average to be around $4.5\pm \sqrt {(.5^2+1.5^2+2.5^2+3.5^2+4.5^2)/5/45}\approx 4.5\pm .43$. That means that $7.5$ is within 7 sigma which, so you’ll expect extreme examples around 1 in $10^{12}$ times, but that’ll occur for around a thousand 15 digit numbers.
If you do this for $10^n$, you’ll find that the noise in the mean is $\sqrt{2.75/n}$, so if you’re cutoff is $c$, you’ll need at least $(c-4.5)\sqrt{n/2.75}$ standard deviations. The normal tail is approximately proportional to $e^{-z^2/2}/z$, so this probability $e^{-(c-4.5)^2/5.5 n}/\sqrt{n}$ occurring for around $10^n$ numbers. This suggests that there’s a cutoff $C=4.5+\sqrt{5.5\ln{10}}\approx 8.06$. If your cutoff is less than $C$ (as in this case), the number of large numbers increases faster than the distribution narrows and you end up with infinitely many examples. If your cutoff is larger, the reverse happens and you’d expect a finite number of examples.

Interesting---this raises the question, what is the first example whose average value exceeds that of the first cube, $8$?

We have to be careful however since the average is not a variable with an arbitary real value. The value is limited by $9$. Not sure how this influences the probability distribution , apart from that it is anyway only a heuristic.

That said , I found huge cases of the form $10^a-10^b-10^c-1$ , for which the digit average of the cube exceeds even $8.2$ , for example the triple $[a,b,c]=[575, 432, 288]$

Neat! Didn’t think the assumption of randomness would be that false, but that’s a pretty good class of examples. I updated my post with appropriate Caveats.
